# Changing android actionbar style

Tags: android

I am currently trying to set the color, title, and icon of the action bar on my launcher page. This is what I have done so far:

```
public class MainDisplay extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_display);

        setTitle("ok");
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setIcon(R.drawable.mylogo);

        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")));
    }

}
```

However, when I try this, the action bar first looks like the old style, and then gets changed to this new style. I would like for the action bar not to look like the old style for that moment, and instead go right to the new style. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just declare it in the manifest like this.

```
<activity
        android:name=".LauncherPage"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/mylogo" 
</activity>
```